# remote_transport_exception: When partially updating elasticsearch document using script

Tags: php, elasticsearch, lucene

I am partially updating the document using the following structure

```
$params = [
                'index' => self::$currentIndex[self::INDEX_TYPE_SEARCH],
                'type'  => self::TYPE_PRODUCT,
                'id'    => $product_id,
                'body'  => [
                    'script' => 'ctx._source.coupons += coupon',
                    'params' => ['coupon' => array($product_body)],
                ]
            ];
```

However I am getting the following error:

> remote_transport_exception:
>   [Gee][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]

Any idea if the structure is incorrect?

Comment: The issue was with the existing document structure. The old coupons structure differed from the new coupon structure because of which I was getting the error:  `{"error" : "reason":"failed to run inline script [ctx._source.coupons+=coupon] using lang [groovy]","caused_by":{"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry"}}},"status":400}"`

Answer (score 4):

If you wan't to add values to an array than you can do this,

```
$params['id'] = $product_id;
$params['body'] = array(
            'script' => array(
                "inline" => "ctx._source.coupons.add(params.coupon)",
                "lang" => "painless",
                "params" => ['coupon' => array($product_body)]
            )
        );
```

This thould work as it worked for me.